# Prove that if $A \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set with volume and $R$ is an $n$-rectangle such that $R \subset A$, then $A \setminus R$ has volume.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Prove/disprovethat if $A \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set with volume and $R$ is an $n$-rectangle such that $R \subset A$, then $A \setminus R$ has volume.

I'm not actually sure if this is true, but it sounds like something that should be true.

I'm defining volume in the following manner by the way:

If $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $A$ is said to have volume if the integral $\int_A 1_A$ exists, where $1_A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be the characteristic function, i.e. the function such that $1_A(a) = 1$ is $a \in A$ and $1_A(a) = 0$ if $a \not \in A$.

An $n$-rectangle is a set of the form $\prod_{i = 1}^n [x_i, y_i]$ where $x_i < y_i$.

For a rectangle $B$, $v(B) = \prod_{i = 1}^n (y_i - x_i)$. Define the lower sum of $f$ for $P$ (a partition that divides $[x_i, y_i]$ by points $a_0^i, \dotsm, a_{m_i}^i$ and forming $m_1m_2 \dotsm m_n$ rectangles $[a_{j_1}^1, a_{j_1 + 1}^1] \times \dotsm \times [a_{j_n}^n, a_{j_n + 1}^n]$ where $0 \leq j_i \leq m_i - 1$) as

$$L(f, P) = \sum_{R \in P} \inf\{f(x) | x \in R \} v(R)$$, and the upper sum is defined similarly.

Suppose $A$ is a bounded set and $f:A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then the integral, if it exists, is defined by first enclosing $A$ in a rectangle $B$, and then calculating the supremum of the lower sums or the infinimum of the upper sums.

Comment: "$A$ is said to have volume if the integral $\int_A 1_A$ exists" Do you mean $\int_{\mathbb R^n}1_A$? because $\int_A 1_A$ is simply equal to $\int_A 1$...

Comment: It's best to put the question being asked in the body of the post, not just the title.

Comment: @5xum I'm using Mardsen-Hoffman, which defines an integral on non-rectangular sets $A$ by first enclosing it in a rectangular set $B$, and then computes the lower and upper sums over a partition of $B$ to define that integral. So I think it uses the notation $\int_A 1_A$ because that equals $\int_B 1_A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rectangle $R$ is closed, so its complement $\bar{R}$ is open. Then the intersection $A\setminus  R=A\cap\bar{R} $ is open and non-empty. This finishes the proof, since every non-empty open set has non-zero volume (e.g. it contains an $n$-rectangle of volume $\epsilon^n$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170627/does-every-non-empty-open-set-has-measure-greater-than-zero)).